# Expose custom claims in SCIM2 endpoints - WSO2

Tags: wso2, scim, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 v5.7, I added a custom claims namely "**`status`**" through Local claims and added a respective External claims too.

**Local Claim:**
[image]

**External Claim:**
[image]

**WSO2 IS Portal: Shows the newly added claim namely `Status`**
[image]

I triggered the SCIM2 End point https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/ee02b02a-f601-4d7c-a34b-767a7bb4521f

[image]

But the newly created claims was missing in the response JSON data.I update the value for the said claim through **WSO2 IS portal** and its stored the value in the database table `um_user_attribute` as a key value pair.

Kindly assist me how to expose the locally created claims in **SCIM2** endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding claim configuration is not enough to get custom claim. You have to add them to SCIM 2.0 User schema by modifying **scim2-schema-extension.config** please refer [1] for exact steps given for SCIM 1.1

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Extensible+SCIM+User+Schemas+With+WSO2+Identity+Server

Comment: Could you please assist me, how to pass values for those claims while on Create user end point?

Comment: "EnterpriseUser":{"department":"xxx","costCenter":"yyy"} how ever attributes depends on how you define attributes in scim2-schema-extension.config. I would suggest  you to go to bottom of scim2-schema-extension.config and understand the structure first.

Comment: what about with scim 2 how this link help me with scim2

Comment: I have added on both places for wso2 5.6 still can't get the required custom values.